# Preservation of SQLite data with iOS app update

Tags: sql, ios, xcode, sqlite

This may seem like an absurd question, however thought I best double check beforehand.

I am deciding which sort of data storage method to use, and currently using SQLite (libsqllite2.dylib).

If I were to release an update for the app through the app store, would the data within the database be preserved or deleted once the iPhone app was updated?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in your sandbox that's not in the bundle -- anything you put in your Documents folder, Library folder, etc. -- is retained. Only the app bundle itself is replaced.

Comment: How would you store a database there? Is the above for iOS?

Comment: @user1202278 It is for iOS. If you ship you app with a built-in sqlite database in the bundle then you can't modify that database without modifying the bundle (which iOS won't let you do). As a result, if your app is already modifying a database then either you created it in one of those folders after first launch, or if you had one in the bundle when the app was installed and you're modifying it, you must have copied it out of the bundle into one of those folders and worked with it from there. Does that make sense?